# To find the point slope

Tags: calculus

Can you please help me?

The line $-4x-2y+14=0$ slopes to graph of function $f(x)=x^3-x^2+4x$.
Find point of slope...

I don't really understand how to solve this question.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it seems like the question is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your line is $$y=-2x+7$$
That line is a slopes the graph of the differentiable function $f$ if and only if there exists a point $x_0\in D_f$ so that $f^{\prime}(x_0)=-2$ (can you see where $-2$ comes from?) and $y=f(x_0)$. That $x_0$ is your point of slope. You shall end up with a system of equations that has no solutions... and so the problem is wrong